# grafana+prometheus using influx DB

Tags: prometheus, grafana, influxdb, influxql

We have existing Grafana dashboards which use Prometheus as a source and query for data using PromQL.
Since we want to keep the data longer (e.g.: 2months) and data volume is quite significant, we switched Prometheus to Influx DB, using remote_write and remote_read:
https://devopstales.github.io/monitoring/prometheus-influxdb/

Is it possible to switch Grafana dashboards to use the data stored in influx in our configuration and existing dashboards and retrieve data from InfluxDB using the existing PromQL queries?

Thanks in advance for help